# How to change default IP on MySQL using Dockerfile

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, typeorm

Is there a way to change IP on MySQL using Dockerfile? I have a problem with my app.

I have this configuration:

```
let ormConfig: any;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  // test environment database should be drop every time. so synchronize should be true for this config
  ormConfig = {
    type: 'mysql',
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    // host: 'localhost', // not needed if run on docker
    username: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'test_db',
    synchronize: true,
    dropSchema: true,
    entities: ['src/models/**/*.ts']
  };
} else {
  ormConfig = {
    type: 'mysql',
    host: 'db', // docker service database name
    // host: 'localhost', // not needed if run on docker
    // port: 3306, // not needed if run on docker
    username: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'development_db',
    synchronize: false,
    logging: true,
    entities: ['src/models/**/*.ts'],
    migrations: ['db/migrations/**/*.ts'],
    subscribers: ['src/subscribers/**/*.ts'],
    cli: {
      entitiesDir: 'src/models',
      migrationsDir: 'db/migrations',
      subscribersDir: 'src/subscribers'
    }
  };
}

export = ormConfig;
```

I'm using typeorm for my ORM. On else block I have a host name `db` this works when connecting to my db if I'm using my application, but when I tried running a migration I have to change the host to `0.0.0.0` and found out that it's because of the docker MySQL container (server_db image):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
aaaa4d178537        server_server       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp              server_server_1
e5021687b86b        server_db           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   server_db_1
```

I'm just tired of changing and changing it before and after migration.

Any idea just to use localhost? or custom IP like `1.2.3.456` something like that?

Also here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    build: ./db
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - app_network
  server:
    depends_on:
      - "db" # this is important for sql connection. it has to wait for mysql to establish connection then run this bish
    build: .
    command: ["npm", "run", "dev"]
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - /server/node_modules/ # added this because of bcrypt elm error
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /server # this name is from dockerfile workdir
    networks:
      - app_network

networks:
  app_network:
volumes:
  app_volume:
```

and my db Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:8.0.18
EXPOSE 3306
COPY ./init_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

### Update

To answer @ckaserer's question:

> Where are you running the migration from? e.g. are you trying to connect from your workstation/docker host to the mysql container?

I'm running it outside the container through npm with a command `npm run migration:run`

> Any error logs you can share?

The error is saying cannot connect to `db:3306`, that's why I have to change it to `0.0.0.0:3306`.

> Can you clarify your migration workflow and where it fails? (including from which system it is executed. e.g. container x, workstation,..)

The migration happens outside the container using typeOrm cli, I create a migration, then cli will check my `ormconfig.ts` and will check the else block for the type and host. (I'm not sure if this is what your asking)

### Update

Here's the error if I run the migration:

`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db db:3306` the IP:Port is the problem. grrrr.

Link to Code repository: https://github.com/artoodeeto/ggpo-server

Answer (score 3):

## Verify

check if you can reproduce the following on your host while your containers are running.

#### 1) start your app

simply execute `docker-compose up`

#### 2) connect to db

try to connect to your mysql database from your host machine like this

```
mysql -u root -ppassword -h 127.0.0.1
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 9
Server version: 8.0.18 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
#+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| development_db     |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| production_db      |
| sys                |
| test_db            |
+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

## But why does that work?

A few things here. First off, your `ormconfig.ts` is correct for your application within the container. Your `server` container wants to connect to `db` container. That works. In your docker-compose file you explicitly exposed the `db` port `3306` to all available interfaces on your host. You can check that by running

```
docker container ls
8b5c4dc41892        ggpo-server_server   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   47 hours ago        Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp              ggpo-server_server_1
a0ca405d8020        ggpo-server_db       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   47 hours ago        Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   ggpo-server_db_1
```

This translates to your database being available on your host at `127.0.0.1:3306` and `[HOST-IP]:3306`. This is why the previous mysql connect worked with `127.0.0.1`.

## But why does my migration not work?

Here we go! Like I stated, your `ormconfig.ts`is correct for your app within the container - but not if you want to connect to the database from your host. your host does not know about the DNS name `db` so your `ormconfig.ts` will not work. In order to access it from your host you need `host: localhost`, and for your server to work you need `host: db`. But you can't set both. Therefore you might want to introduce some kind of additional env config that distinguishes between the 2 scenarios.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  // test environment database
  ...
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local') {
  // new config with host: localhost
} else {
  // default
}
```

---

## Original answer from 9.01.2020

No, you can not assign a fixed IP to an image in your dockerfile. This would break portability and scalability since the IP needs to be unique.

The `host` binding to `0.0.0.0` is what you need in that case. It binds the mysql service to all available network interfaces. In your case to `localhost` and `app_network` within the container.

Therefore you are able to reach the container from any other container inside your `app_network` or you could go into the `db` container and execute your migration directly via mysql connection to `localhost`.

### access to the db from your workstation

You are almost there. You already have the port exposure definition for your `db` in your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

However, you can not access the container by its name from the outside world. The port exposure definition `port` tells docker to forward any traffic that your host gets on `3306` to the `db` container on port `3306`. That said, you can, therefore, access the `db` from your host by using your hosts IP or hostname, since you are already on the machine that runs the container you can simply use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in your migration.

You need to change the ormconfig.ts that you use for your migration. In particular the `host` entry value from `db` to `localhost`.

```
{
   "type": "mysql",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 3306,
   "username": "test",
   "password": "test",
   "database": "test"
}
```

That should fix your issue.

---

## Bonus

#### 1) Why can't I assign an IP to an image

An image is not running, therefore no IP assignment.
You can, however, specify a fixed IP to your container in your docker-compose.yml like this

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: busybox
    command: ifconfig
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.18.10

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.18.18.0/24
        gateway: 172.18.18.1
```

#### 2) why you should not do 1)

An IP is a unique identifier of a system in that particular network. So what happens when you would like to have 2 instances of `app`?

```
docker-compose up --scale app=2
Creating network "playground_app_net" with driver "bridge"
Creating playground_app_1 ... done
Creating playground_app_2 ... error

ERROR: for playground_app_2  Cannot start service app: b'Address already in use'

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: b'Address already in use'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Docker tells you that the IP address is already in use by the first instantiation of `app` and can not be assigned again.

Comment: thanks for responding sir. I appreciate it so much. I have answered your question please check update response. I have a question though why is it not portable and scalable if docker would assign a specific IP? if a user can assign a specific IP then it would dynamic and can just use that IP from that image right? sorry, im not really a devops im learning this for work. thank you

Comment: @aRtoo thank you for the detailed info. Please check the updated answer ;)

Comment: hello sir. that `localhost` was my implementation before and it failed because my app could access it. it gives me this error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306` but when I use `db` its working. thank you for providing me an explanation. :)

Comment: @aRtoo, does that mean you fixed your problem? If so, please update this answer to reflect what you changed an accept it or provide additional information for me to update the answer such that the community can benefit from the solution as well (and I am curious too).

Comment: @aRtoo, `localhost` was your implementation where? in the app? e.g. the container based on the `docker-compose` service `server` which is part of the `app_network`? If so, your statement is correct, that can't work. Since you do not have your DB running locally inside the `server` container. However, you can use the service name `db` to connect to the database container from the `server` container since both containers share the same network.

Comment: hello sir, thank you again and I really appreciate your response. I didnt fixed the problem, its still the same. for instance when I use DBMS `tableplus` the host that I need to input is `0.0.0.0` instead of `db` which is my container, or `localhost` (doesnt work) because i think (this is just my theory) when I do a `docker ps` my db container is showing a port `0.0.0.0:3306` the IP is `0.0.0.0` is the one i need to use to connect to my container outside docker. what I wanted if you say I cant set a static IP is change `0.0.0.0` to `localhost` is that possible?

Comment: for the migration. when is set my host to `db` and run a command `npm run migration:run` it fails so im manually swtiching from `db` to `0.0.0.0` every time i run a migration.

Comment: Could you share a slimed down version that still produces the and share it? E.g github repo with all the files required to reproduce your issue?

Comment: heres my [repo](https://github.com/artoodeeto/ggpo-server). i haven't done much yet as I was busy. thank you again sir.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code, I’ll try to squeeze it in tomorrow or the day after that if no one else is faster.

Comment: hello sir. thank for this. thank you thank you. ill try this when I get home. I didnt know about that `local` I didnt explicitly said `local` somewhere but ill add that on my package.json when I run migration

Comment: Ah. Good point there. `Local` (or whichever value you choose) only work if you set the environment variable accordingly. I am by no means a JavaScript / npm expert, so you still have to figure out how to properly do that. Otherwise I would have already created a pull request ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can run both of your services in network_mode:"host" and then your both application will run on machine's localhost network. No need to map port in this case just remove ports.

Comment: hello sir. where should I put the `network_mode:"host"` in docker-compose file? under `app_network:`? or each of the services?

Comment: hellow sir. I got this error though. `ERROR: 'network_mode' and 'networks' cannot be combined`

Comment: define network_mode for each service and remove networks and app_network.

Comment: it work but theres no ports available. when I dot `docker ps -a` the theres is no PORTS being exposed. it useless because it cant be access outside the app

Comment: network_mode =host will expose your port on host machine. No need to worry. Direct access using localhost:portNumber

Comment: it wasnt working. the app cant access port `8000`. maybe we theres away to add port or customize it?