# TypeORM CLI does not recognice the postgres host through the docker-compose

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, typeorm

I am creating an application in nodejs, with typescript, postgres and typeorm, to help in my development I put this all to start with docker. I'm using the network "bridge" and the connections between the containers are ok. The problem is when I want to run a migration using the TypeORM CLI. The CLI simply does not recognize my host that is set in my ormconfig.json as "postgres". The funny thing is that when I change the host on ormconfig.json to "localhost" the CLI works perfectly, but I lose the connection to the database, and when I put the host as "postgres" the connection to the database works but the CLI to run the migrations does not.

This is the TypeORM CLI error when trying to run migrations:

```
yarn typeorm migration:run
yarn run v1.22.0
$ ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run
Using ts-node version 8.10.2, typescript version 3.9.7
Error during migration run:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:64:26) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'postgres'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  api_cadunico:
    container_name: api_cadunico
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    command: yarn start:dev
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    networks:
      - connection_cadunico
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      TZ: America/Fortaleza
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - connection_cadunico
networks:
  connection_cadunico:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

ormconfig.json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "default",
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "postgres",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "cadunico",
    "database": "cadunico_atendimento",
    "entities": [
      "./src/entities/*.ts"
    ],
    "migrations": [
      "./src/database/migrations/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
      "migrationsDir": "./src/database/migrations"
    }
  }
]
```

What do I need to do to run the migrations without having to change the host to localhost and normally use the docker's network host?

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is kind of late. To anyone looking for answers to this question, you have to run all your typeorm commands inside your application's container by accessing it with `docker exec -it your-container-name-or-id sh`.

If you're using typescript, you need `ts-node` as devDependency and run typeorm's CLI with `./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js`.

Here are some useful resources:

[How to change default IP on mysql using Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639845/how-to-change-default-ip-on-mysql-using-dockerfile)

https://typeorm.io/#/faq/how-to-handle-outdir-typescript-compiler-option